# Why does X not start and xinit abort?

Tags: login, kde, xserver

For the last four weeks i haven't been able to access my Kubuntu graphic environment.

After loging in this page appears for about one second

[image]

after that the login screen appears again with no sign of an error (be it a wrong password etc...).

When trying to log into the console there's no problem, but starting x from the console results in this error

[image]

What I've already tried:

- reinstalling kde-desktop-environment
- installing and changing from lightdm to kdm and back
- checking all .Xauthority files and chown them to my account
- reinstalling xterm
- reinstalling xserver-xorg

none of the above worked.

What i did before the error occured:

- installed some canonical&partner updates
- added a script to autostart

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

About the error in the first screen (/etc/rc2.d/S99tpb: tpb: not found )
reinstall IBM thinkpad buttons software or remove softlink "S99tpb" from /etc/rc2.d

About the second screen (and the question in the subject line):

1) The script that you added to autostart has to be removed first (because it is probably the reason for this behaviour).

2) post your /var/log/Xorg.0.log

3) post the script that you added to autostart

What I want you to do next:

Uninstall virualbox for the time being

add a new user from scratch and log in as that user and tell me if that works okay.